# making .srt file using values from two columns of database

Tags: c#, database, gps, location

I am making a desktop application in C#. This Application gets a video recorded from a camera and saves it. At the same time the application gets the values of longitude and latitude of the GPS attached with it. It saves the GPS values in to a database.

I want to make an .SRT file which have those coordinate values from database using c#. How would i do it? Please help. Later i want to save that .SRT file into a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

```
                    /************Getting value from database and saving into .srt************/

                    #region Save Srt file 

                    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(database.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Connection.Open();

                            using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand(Query, Connection))
                            {
                                using (SqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command))
                                {
                                    using (DataTable Table = new DataTable())
                                    {
                                        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                        DataAdapter.Fill(Table);
                                        if (Table.Rows.Count > 0)
                                        {
                                            // create a writer and open the file
                                            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(TxtSrtName.Text + ".srt");

                                            foreach (DataRow rows in Table.Rows)
                                            {



                                                // write a line of text to the file


                                                tw.WriteLine(rows["Id"].ToString());
                                                tw.WriteLine(rows["Time"].ToString() + "-->" + rows["Time"].ToString());
                                                tw.WriteLine(rows["Long"] + " " + rows["Lat"]);
                                                tw.WriteLine("");




                                                // close the stream



                                            }
                                            tw.Close();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            LblLatitude.Text = "No Lattitude";
                                            LblLongitude.Text = "No Longitude";
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally { Connection.Close(); }
                    }
                    #endregion

                    /**********************************************************************/
```